# Does network-wide deletion exist to be performed by Community Managers for spammers/trolls?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts, network-wide-suspension

Staff can issue a network-wide suspension for a user for an arbitrary number of days. Even for hundreds of years.

I'm interested to know if there is also a network-wide deletion path which Community Managers can use for spammers/trolls, as opposed to network-wide deletion at the request of the user. If there’s no such thing, what's the background of this, and why is it not possible/implemented?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Do you want to delete your account network wide? If not I can't see what one would do with this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: I've seen accounts deleted network-wide, where the only contributions of that account were egregious spam, so I'm pretty sure they can and do delete network-wide

Comment: @Lino I can ask you the same question "Why do you want to know why I'm interested of this?" My post is the normal [support] question about how the system works. I don't want to delete my own profile, don't be afraid of that.

Comment: [No such thing](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8706533#8706533), CM has to manually delete the account on each site before being able to delete the network profile itself.

Comment: I have often wondered this. If a user gets destroyed for spam and nonsense posts on one site, why are they allowed to continue their accounts (and thus spamming/nonsense) on other sites? It makes little or no sense, to me.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack Your statement here is inaccurate, due to being outdated. See: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9499264#9499264. CMs now have a button to nuke the account and all profiles in one action.

Comment: @Makyen ha, didn't see/remember it. Well, guess you can post that as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, network-wide deletion exists

Yes, network-wide deletion exists, and has existed for a long time. It's very rarely used for anything other than network-wide spammers. For other types of issues, including network-wide trolls, account merger into a main account that is suspended network-wide has generally been the method of resolving such accounts, once Community Managers have gotten involved. There are a variety of reasons for that, some of which are shared only with moderators.

However, a major reason for account merger to be more common historically over network-wide account deletion is that, in the past, network account deletion for things like spam was *significantly* more work for Community Managers. The Community Manager would have to individually go to each network site where a profile existed for the user and separately delete/destroy the user's profile on each site. Only after they did that could the Community Manager then proceed to delete/destroy the network account.

Recently, the functionality was added to the system to make it possible for Community Managers to destroy spammers network-wide with much less effort. That was completed a some time relatively shortly prior to [JNat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat) [saying in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9499264#9499264):

> in any case, I now have a button to just nuke these, so it should be much easier going forward ^_^

So, Community Managers now have a button to nuke spammers' accounts network-wide.

It is, however, still more likely that such accounts will be handled by the individual site profile being nuked by a site moderator, without addressing the network account, because such issues are primarily escalated from users first to site moderators (or site moderators see it first), and destroying the user's profile and content on the individual moderator's site is the primary action which site moderators are able to do. Performing network-wide destruction/merger is not possible for site moderators, so further escalation to Community Managers would be needed. Doing so is not usually needed in most cases, so the extra work isn't typically performed.

Comment: Interesting. If the network-wide deletion exists should we consider the [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389456/339911) to be reopened?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ One of the answers on the exiting duplicates explicitly answers that question and the other answers and question provide more context, so I'd say "no" it shouldn't be reopened.